# Creating and passing parameters in by name

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm doing a `foreach` loop on the parameters of a method.

```
MethodInfo objMethoda = typMyService.GetMethod(
                                        "GetBySystemWarrantyId",
                                        Type.EmptyTypes);
ParameterInfo[] pars = objMethoda.GetParameters();
foreach (ParameterInfo p in pars)
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}",p.ParameterType , p.Name);
```

When I try to invoke it, I get parameters that don't match.

My method has 5 parameters:

```
 System.String whereClause
 System.String orderBy
 System.Int32 start
 System.Int32 pageLength
 out System.Int32& totalCount
```

Can I create those arguments and pass it into the method?

`var dataTableObjecta = objMethoda.Invoke(oMyServicea, null);`

For example: the parameters, in the same order as above, would be

```
"1=1"
""
0
100000
out totalCount
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the below example

Method

```
public void GetBySystemWarrantyId(string whereClause, string orderBy, int start, int end, out int totalCount )
{
    totalCount = 3;
}
```

Usage

```
MethodInfo objMethoda = this.GetType().GetMethod("GetBySystemWarrantyId");
int cnt = 0;
object[] parameters = {"1=1", "", 0, 100000, cnt};
objMethoda.Invoke(this, parameters);
int parsedNumber = (int)parameters[4];
```

What I found was that if you don't pass the parameters in as a predeclared array of objects but merely as below

```
objMethoda.Invoke(this, new object[] { "1=1", "", 0, 100000, cnt });
```

the return value is not stored in `cnt`

Answer (score 2):

In order to invoke using the parameters, do the following:

```
var parameters = new [] {"1=1", "", 0, 100000,  totalCount};
var dataTableObjecta = objMethoda.Invoke(oMyServicea, parameters);
```

The value of `parameters[4]` will be changed according to the function.

Answer (score 1):

You are specifying the wrong method signature. [`Type.EmptyTypes` indicates a method with no parameters.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.emptytypes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) You need to specify any array of the proper types or specify no types at all.

[Here it is as a DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/OnEbsJ).

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

public class MyService
{
    public void GetBySystemWarrantyId(string whereClause, string orderBy, 
        int start, int pageLength, out int totalCount)
    {
        totalCount = 1234567890;
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        MethodInfo objMethoda = typeof(MyService)
             .GetMethod("GetBySystemWarrantyId", new Type[]
             {
                typeof (string), typeof (string), 
                typeof (int), typeof (int), typeof (int).MakeByRefType()
             });

        MethodInfo objMethodb = typeof(MyService)
             .GetMethod("GetBySystemWarrantyId");

        int count= -1;
        object[] args = new object[] { "", "", 1, 1, count };

        objMethoda.Invoke(new MyService(), args);
        Console.WriteLine(args[4]);

        objMethodb.Invoke(new MyService(), args);
        Console.WriteLine(args[4]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Shaun - how do you make typeof(MyService) reflective?  so I can just pass a string to that instead of typeof(MyService)

Comment: @Mike While I'm not entirely sure what you mean, maybe you could use `(new MyService()).GetType()` because it returns a string.

Comment: @Mike What does "reflective" mean?